# chown folder/file create with PHP

Tags: php, file-permissions

`chown()` is the function used to change the ownership of the file/folder. But if file is created with PHP, the group and owner is `apache` and users on linux(`apache` in this case) can't change the owner to another user. Only `root` can do that.

So, if a folder is created using `mkdir("path/folder", 0775, true);`, than `folder` has an owner and group `apache`. subsequent `chown("path/folder", "different_user")` calls will fail with "Operation not permitted error".

Now, I do not want to change permissions to 775, just to be able to read the file, because only 1 user + apache needs to access the file, not everyone. This sounds like a standard problem. What is the standard way of fixing ownership of files created with php?

Comment: If apache is the only user you want to be able to read the file, wouldn't this be chmod 400?

Comment: I want 2 users to be able to read the file, apache + the one I use when sshing to server.

Comment: If the user is in the apache group(which I assume apache is), then add the user you login as to the apache group and 440 should allow you to read it as well.